# Change Number of Pages in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

I am using a `UIScrollView` that has several items that need to be displayed. I currently have the first item centered in the middle of the `UIScrollView` when it is first loaded. I am trying to have the next item, the second item, be partially shown allowing the user to know that there are more items to be seen, hence causing them to scroll through the items.

What I am trying to do is configure it so that the user is free to swipe and scroll just as the `UIScrollView` permits, however each time the user swipes, I want the `UISCrollView` to automatically stop on whichever item is most near the center of the view.

I have enabled paging and understand how the paging works. What I am trying to do is make it so that I can **change** the number of "fixed page points" that paging seems to create. With paging enabled, it seems to divide the total width of the view by 2, creating 3 points of stopping: one at the end of the view at the left bound, one in the direct center (view width / 2 ), and one at the far right bound of the view.

If anyone knows how to change the number of stopping points, or page points (CGPoints), whatever they may be called, I would be very appreciative. Below is an image of what I am trying to achieve.

1. the view loads with the first item centered in the middle.
2. the user has scrolled to the right, and stopped on item 2, which is then displayed in the center of the screen now.
3. again the user as scrolled right, with item 3 now centered.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, UIScrollView paging does not work in the way that you want it to.

The paging creates as many sections as it can of the Bounds of the UIScrollView within the size of the Content. For example, if your scrollview has a frame size of 200x200 and your content is 400x200, it will create two horizontal pages. If it is 600x200, it will create three horizontal pages and so on.

This means that you will not be able to page in such a way that you can see the other elements.

In order to do that, I would recommend overriding this method:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

Here is an example of this in use for the same effect as full paging. I would play with the targetOffset line with the size of your elements to make it all work.

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {

    float expectedOffset = targetContentOffset->x;
    if (expectedOffset == 0 || expectedOffset == scrollView.contentSize.width)
        return;
    CGFloat targetOffset = roundf(expectedOffset / scrollView.frame.size.width) * scrollView.frame.size.width;

    targetContentOffset->x = targetOffset;
}
```

Comment: thanks mate - i'll give this a try. Maybe I can mess around with a containerview or something to try and at least make it look good lol.

Comment: is there a way to just programmatically go to a specific point in the scroll view?

Comment: @WillVonUllrich Set the [`contentOffset`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) property of the scrollview.

Comment: The difference with setting the contentOffset property is that it won't animate smoothly. It creates a new animation that gets completed after the touch has been released instead of pre-computing its destination (which is what my above solution does). It works, but it won't look nearly as smooth.

Comment: yea i see what you mean. I set up an switch case to see which item is in view, forcing it to center to that object but not too much better aesthetically there either.